# Azure Data Factory : Update input dataset and rerun the pipeline programmatically without re-initialization of the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a copy activity to move data from csv file stored in the Data lake store to Azure SQL database.

The user needs to specify which file to move then execute the copy activity and this to be done from our web application. So to  be done programmatically I used the [Azure Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt415885.aspx) to update the pipeline through [Create or Update pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906741.aspx).

The problem that it re-intializes the whole pipeline again which increases time dramatically,is there any way to just change the dataset and re-run the pipeline(without re-intializations) ?